# Convert object into array in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code which works fine

```
 public function success(Request $request)
 {
    $paymentstatus=$request->input('status');
    $transactionid=$request->input('txnid');
    Ticket::where('transactionid',$transactionid)->update(['paymentstatus'=>$paymentstatus]);
    $ticketdata=Ticket::with('eventdetail')->where('transactionid',$transactionid)->first();

    $venuename=$ticketdata->eventdetail->venuename;
    $eventname=$ticketdata->eventdetail->eventname;
    $eventdate=Carbon::parse($ticketdata->eventdetail->eventdate)->format('d M Y');


 $myticketdata=array('ticketid'=>'200','class'=>'gold','no_of_persons'=>'10','fullname'=>'tommy dollar','email'=>'xya@gmail.com','mobile'=>'9874563210','transactionid'=>'alskdjflaskjdflakjd');

   EmailController::sendemail($ticketdata->email,$myticketdata);

    return "success";
}
```

But I want to send array which is fetched by using below given line

```
$ticketdata=Ticket::with('eventdetail')->where('transactionid',$transactionid)->first();
```

So in above function i changed this line to

```
EmailController::sendemail($ticketdata->email,$ticketdata);
```

But after executing this code, I get this error
[image]

I know this error is because i am not passing array to this function, but I am unable to rectify this code.
I also tried to typecast object to array but that did't worked here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `$ticketdata` is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, you can use the `toArray()` method to convert it to an array:

```php
$ticketdata = Ticket::with('eventdetail')
    ->where('transactionid', $transactionid)
    ->first()
    ->toArray();
```

http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_toArray

Answer (score 0):

```
 $status = \Mail::send('emails.templete_name', ['ticketdata' => $ticketdata, 'somethingelse'=> 'somethingelse'], function($message) use ($ticketdata)
            {
                $message->to($ticketdata->email, 'text')->subject('text');
            });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The code to send emails is behind `EmailController::sendemail()`. The parameterlist of this method requires the second parameter to be of type array. The OP asked for a way to convert his model to an array.

Comment: the error displayed in the email, should that the error is in the calling for the Mail:send  not the EmailController::sendmail() . most probably he is using it in inside the sendmail()

Answer (score 0):

Try this to have your data in array:

```
$ticketdata=Ticket::with('eventdetail')->where('transactionid',$transactionid)->first()->toArray();
```